# How to resize div to take the size of a background image

Tags: css

I would like to resize a div according to its background image responsively

now, I have something like 
[image]

And I would like the div to take the size of the football-field background image.

this is a fiddle with a more basic test, if you can help me to figure it out..
http://jsfiddle.net/jibe84/dahmfq60/

```
.zones-activity {
padding: 5px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/200/300');
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: so do you want to stretch the background image to full width, so there is no repeat ?

Comment: yes, and the height  will be updated to keep the right ratio to not deform the football field

Comment: Anything like this; http://jsfiddle.net/dahmfq60/5/ ?
I'm kind of confused sorry.